# Compare two vectors within a data frame with %in% with R

Tags: r, vector

**Compare two vectors within a data frame with %in%**

I have the following data

`T1 <- data.frame( "Col1" = c("a", "b", "aa", "d"), "Col2" = c("a,b,c", "aa,c,d", "c,d,e", "d,f,g") )`

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | a,b,c |
| b | aa,c,d |
| aa | c,d,e |
| d | d,f,g |

I want to select the rows that contain a character from this vector c("a", "e", "g"), specifying the columna

`library(dplyr)`

`T1 %>%  filter(Col1 %in% c("a", "e", "g"))`

I returned

`1    a a,b,c`

It is correct, but if I want to compare two vectors, example:

With unlist and strsplit, I transform the value of each row to a character vector and try to compare it with the reference vector to select the rows that contain any of the values:

`unlist(strsplit(T1$Col2[1],","))`

`[1] "a" "b" "c"`

`T1 %>%  filter(unlist(strsplit(Col2,",")) %in% c("a", "e", "g"))`

It gives me an error:
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = unlist(strsplit(Col2, ",")) %in% c("a", "e", "g")`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 12.
Run  `]8;;rstudio:run:rlang::last_error()rlang::last_error() ]8;;` to see where the error occurred.

I can do it like this:

`T1[grep(c("a|e|g"), T1$Col2),]`

`1    a  a,b,c`

`2    b aa,c,d`

`3   aa  c,d,e`

`4    d  d,f,g`

But it's wrong, row `3 aa c,d,e`, shouldn't be, because it's not `a`, it's `aa`

To search for the `"a"` alone, you would have to do:

`T1[grep(c("\\<a\\>"), T1$Col2),]`

I think that with this form I will end up making a mistake, it would give me more security to be able to do it comparing vector with vector:

`T1 %>%  filter(unlist(strsplit(Col2,",")) %in% c("a", "e", "g"))`

Comment: Your code is looking for any of a, e, g in column **two**, for which it correctly reports an e in the string "c, d, e" in row 3.

Comment: @I_O: Sorry, I wanted to put 2    b aa,c,d, not 3   aa  c,d,e but I think the problem is understood, it is not exact, it is giving an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you could achieve this (using your original approach with strsplit) is to do it `rowwise()` and 'sum' the logical test.

```
T1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(unlist(strsplit(Col2,",")) %in% c("a","e","g")) >= 1)
```

Comment: I did not know rowwise, thanks for your contribution, it will be very useful to me : )

Comment: Just beware that you might need to `%>% ungroup` the result as I think rowwise creates a hidden index column and then groups by that index. @Quinten’s grepl approach might be a lot faster for large datasets too!

Answer (score 3):

**Edited answer**

You can use the syntax `\\b` for regular expressions word boundary. The `|` is for boundaries adjacent to like an or operation. You can use the following code:

```r
T1 <- data.frame( "Col1" = c("a", "b", "aa", "d"), "Col2" = c("a,b,c", "aa,c,d", "c,d,e", "d,f,g") )
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
T1 %>% 
  filter(grepl("\\b(a|e|g)\\b", Col2))
#>   Col1  Col2
#> 1    a a,b,c
#> 2   aa c,d,e
#> 3    d d,f,g
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note: `\\b` is for R version 4.1+ otherwise use `\b`.

**old answer**

It returns all rows back because you check if one of the strings exists in Col2 and you can see that in row 3, "e" exists which is one of the strings and that's why it returns also row 4. You could also use `str_detect` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
T1 <- data.frame( "Col1" = c("a", "b", "aa", "d"), "Col2" = c("a,b,c", "aa,c,d", "c,d,e", "d,f,g") )
vector <- c("a", "e", "g")
T1 %>%  
  filter(any(str_detect(Col2, paste0(vector, collapse="|"))))
#>   Col1   Col2
#> 1    a  a,b,c
#> 2    b aa,c,d
#> 3   aa  c,d,e
#> 4    d  d,f,g
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to check if the strings exists, one of them, in both columns. You  can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
T1 <- data.frame( "Col1" = c("a", "b", "aa", "d"), "Col2" = c("a,b,c", "aa,c,d", "c,d,e", "d,f,g") )
vector <- c("a", "e", "g")
T1 %>% 
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(all_of(colnames(T1)), ~str_detect(paste0(vector, collapse="|"), .x))))
#>   Col1  Col2
#> 1    a a,b,c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to put `2    b aa,c,d`, not `3   aa  c,d,e` but I think the problem is understood, it is not exact, it is giving an error

Comment: `T1 %>%  
  filter(any(str_detect(Col2, paste0(c("\\<a\\>", "\\<e\\>", "\\<g\\>"), collapse="|"))))`
This doesn't work either, it returns 0 rows

Comment: Thanks for trying, ¡let's see if someone gets it!

Comment: @Quinten: I don't quite understand ` T1 %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(all_of(colnames(T1)), ~str_detect(paste0(c("a", "e", "g"), collapse="|"), .x))))` . It does NOT return `aa` either, it only returns `a`, but does not return `e` and `g`.

Comment: Hi @LauraMS, I think I found it! Check my edited answer above!

Comment: @TarJae, You were right! I think I found the solution by using `\b` syntax in my edited answer above. I have also been trying a lot of solutions for the match with only `a` ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, it's perfect, but to top it off I add this:
T1 %>% 
  filter(grepl(gsub(",","|", paste0('\\b(', "a,e,g",')\\b')), Col2))

Comment: @Quinten. Good job.